# When Training Model, getting - Value Error target_tensors argument is not supported when executing eagerly

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I tried with eager execution and disabling eager execution with the following code:

```
model = build_encoder_decoder()
final = build_refinement(model)
final.load_weights('/content/gdrive/My Drive/DIM/models/model.01-0.1296.hdf5')
for layer in final.layers:
    layer.trainable = True
import tensorflow as tf
sgd = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.SGD(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
nadam = tensorflow.keras.optimizers.Nadam(lr=2e-5)
tensorflow.compat.v1.disable_eager_execution()
decoder_target = tensorflow.compat.v1.placeholder(dtype='float32', shape=(None, None, None, None))
# final.compile(optimizer=sgd, loss=alpha_prediction_loss)
final.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss=alpha_prediction_loss, target_tensors=[decoder_target],run_eagerly=False)
```

When I try to execute it I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-43-912314147d95> in <module>()
----> 1 final.compile(optimizer=sgd,loss=alpha_prediction_loss, target_tensors=[decoder_target],run_eagerly=False)

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _validate_compile(self, optimizer, metrics, **kwargs)
   2489     if kwargs.pop('target_tensors', None) is not None:
   2490       raise ValueError(
-> 2491           'target_tensors argument is not supported when executing eagerly.')
   2492     invalid_kwargs = set(kwargs) - {
   2493         'experimental_steps_per_execution', 'sample_weight_mode'

ValueError: target_tensors argument is not supported when executing eagerly.
```

I tried disabling eager execution following some methods I found on StackOverflow and other sites, but I keep getting this error.
Can someone tell me where I am going wrong and how i can rectify this?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of tensorflow you're using? You dont need eager_execution in 2.x

Comment: Here are the versions I am using
tensorflow = 2.3.0
keras = 2.4.3